# rank() function usage in Spark SQL

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions, rank

Need some pointers in using `rank()`

I have extracted a column from a dataset..need to do the ranking.

```
Dataset<Row> inputCol= inputDataset.apply("Colname");    
Dataset<Row>  DSColAwithIndex=inputDSAAcolonly.withColumn("df1Rank", rank());

DSColAwithIndex.show();
```

I can sort the column and then append an index column too to get rank...but curious to known syntax and usage of `rank()`

Comment: you have to use window function way since rank and dense_rank are window functions

Comment: What's the error message? Could you please include it in the question?

Comment: Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot evaluate expression: rank()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Window` spec need to be specified for `rank()`

```
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("date") //some spec    

val leadDf = inputDSAAcolonly.withColumn("df1Rank", rank().over(w))
```

**Edit:** Java version of answer, as OP using Java

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec; 
WindowSpec w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(colName);
Dataset<Row> leadDf = inputDSAAcolonly.withColumn("df1Rank", rank().over(w));
```

Comment: Thanks ...tried the below in java....worked fine...                            import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec;              WindowSpec w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(colName);
     Dataset<Row> leadDf = inputDSAAcolonly.withColumn("df1Rank", rank().over(w));

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for this,applying rank over my dataframe in java.

Using the provided answer in above comment,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec; 
WindowSpec w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy(colName);
Dataset<Row> leadDf = inputDSAAcolonly.withColumn("df1Rank", rank().over(w));
```

worked for me,
Thanks 
Gaurav.